# Running a jquery mobile web app in a disconnected state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, android, jquery-mobile

I've been toying with writing a web app using jquery mobile which makes use of forms (cehckboxes, text fields, combo boxes). The tasks the app requires are fairly trivial but the information needs to be updated and sent to a server.

So my question is, say someone uses the app, gets a bunch of data from a server, then loses connection. Will the browser still remember the form fields input and could the user still navigate between pages? From my understanding jquery mobile places all its pages in the same 'webpage' so it's not like it will have to be constantly loading up new data from the server.

My idea is that I'll run some script in the background to check for a connection to a server and when it gets this connection it can go ahead and sync data with the server.

Is this possible or is it a pipe dream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for jquery mobile it append all the data it had in same page so user can use only those links which are already clicked for the links that user have not touch yet will create problem